# Can I use Preprocessor Directives in .ld file

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Can I use Preprocessor Directives in .ld file?
I need to to use one of two sets of .ld file and wants to let Build engine deside that using macro, Can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to run preprocessor manually for your linker script, like this:

```
in="your_linker_script.ld"
out="generated_script.ld"
cflags=-Iinclude/

gcc -E -P -x c $cflags $in >$out
```

Flags:

- `-E` specifies GCC to only run preprocessor
- `-P` prevents preprocessor from generating linemarkers (`#line` directives)
- `-x c` tells GCC to treat your linker script as C source file (it's needed to run GCC with your LD script)

Or you can simply use `cpp` tool, which is actually C preprocessor.

After this you will be able to use generated linker script to build your program (e.g. in Makefile).

### Example

Here is how I solved this problem in my project:

1. [Here](https://github.com/joe-skb7/dra7xx-hello/blob/master/ld/dra7xx.lds) is my linker script uses preprocessor (`#include` directive and `CONFIG_TEXT_BASE` constant). Excerpt:

   ```
    #include <config.h>

    . = CONFIG_TEXT_BASE;
   ```
2. [Here](https://github.com/joe-skb7/dra7xx-hello/blob/master/build/gen-lds.sh#L17) is script to generate preprocessed linker script. Excerpt:

   ```
    gcc -E -P -x c -Iinclude $cflags $in >>$out
   ```
3. [Here](https://github.com/joe-skb7/dra7xx-hello/blob/master/Makefile) is my `Makefile`, it's generating preprocessed linker script at `$(LDS_GEN)` target (line 53) and the this generated script is being used to build result binary (line 42). Excerpt:

   ```
    $(LDS_GEN): $(LDS)
            build/gen-lds.sh $(LDS) $(LDS_GEN) $(CFLAGS)

    $(APP).bin: $(OBJS) $(LDS_GEN)
            $(LD) $(OBJS) -T $(LDS_GEN) -o $(APP).elf
   ```

Comment: Instead of grep for `#` use -P. So the command is `gcc -E -P -x c`

Answer (score 2):

Small update after long time. This way of pre-processing works until the memory file does not contain lines that are fooling the pre-processor. E.g.:

```
"KEEP(*path/*.o(.rodata .rodata*))"
```

The "/*" after path is considered comment start (the line contains what is considered a C multi-line comment start and not a match pattern).

This line is valid for the linker but it is considered comment and the output from C pre-processor will remove everything till a supposed closing comment is found:

```
"KEEP(*path"
```

The resulting file is clearly invalid for the linker. I have no solution at the moment.

Comment: Solved using "-CC" option of the gcc pre-processor:
    gcc -CC -E -x c ...

Comment: A development system I'm using had this pre-processor step for the .ld file built-in to its automated build system.  I solved the problem by changing path/* to path/?*

Answer (score 0):

As a simplification of Sam's answer, I added the below to my makefile and away we go :)

```
PRE_LD_FILE = $(PROG_NAME).ld
LD_FILE = $(PROG_NAME)_generated.ld

$(LD_FILE) : $(PRE_LD_FILE)
    cpp $(PRE_LD_FILE) | grep -v '^#'   >>$(LD_FILE)
```