# Adding a step for building linker script file from template in CMake?

Tags: c, cmake, linker, dependency-management, linker-scripts

Basically, before linking is performed, I would like to convert a GCC linker script template file into a final linker script, as discussed in [Can I use Preprocessor Directives in .ld file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837199/can-i-use-preprocessor-directives-in-ld-file) - and I'd like that step to be performed by Cmake.

I guess my problem is similar to the discussion in [add_custom_command is not generating a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719275/add-custom-command-is-not-generating-a-target) ; but I still cannot see how to solve it. Here is a minimal example, where I'm faking with an empty .ld linker script template file; first, let's create the files using `bash`:

```bash
mkdir /tmp/cmake_test && cd /tmp/cmake_test

touch my_linkerscript_template.ld

cat > main.c <<'EOF'
#include <stdio.h>

const char greeting[] = "hello world";

int main() {
    printf("%s!\n", greeting);
    return 0;
}
EOF

cat > CMakeLists.txt <<'EOF'
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

project(foobar C)
message("PROJECT_NAME is '${PROJECT_NAME}'")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
               main.c
              )

add_compile_options(-Wall
                   )

target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                    "LINKER:--script=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_linkerscript.ld"
                   )
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_linkerscript.ld
                   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_linkerscript_template.ld
                   COMMAND bash ARGS -c "gcc -E -x c -CC -I/usr/include my_linkerscript_template.ld | grep -v '^#' > my_linkerscript.ld"
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   COMMENT "build my_linkerscript_template.ld into my_linkerscript.ld (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})"
                   VERBATIM
                   )
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_linkerscript.ld")
EOF
```

Note that `my_linkerscript.ld` is not created above; as I'd intend to put `my_linkerscript_template.ld` in git, and then have the final `my_linkerscript.ld` generated on demand.

If in this case, I do:

```bash
mkdir /tmp/cmake_test/build && cd /tmp/cmake_test/build
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make
```

I get:

```
$ make
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'D:/msys64/tmp/cmake_test/my_linkerscript.ld', needed by 'foobar.exe'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

$ grep -r linkerscript .
./CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/build.make:foobar.exe: D:/msys64/tmp/cmake_test/my_linkerscript.ld
./CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/build.make:     /D/msys64/mingw64/bin/cc.exe -g -Wl,--script=D:/msys64/tmp/cmake_test/my_linkerscript.ld -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o foobar.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libfoobar.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

So, I did get a dependency on `my_linkerscript.ld`; and it did get added to linker options - but there is no build step generated by the `add_custom_command`.

How can I have generate the proper dependencies, so that when `my_linkerscript.ld` is needed for linking but it does not exist, then commands (that are given in `add_custom_command` above) are run, to generate this file from the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of `add_custom_command` needs to be "consumed" by some target, otherwise the custom command has no effect.

The property `LINK_DEPENDS` does NOT provide a consumer, so you need to create consumer target by yourself:

```
# ... in addition to your code

# Create a consumer target for the linker script.
# So previous `add_custom_command` will have an effect.
add_custom_target(my_linkerscript
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_linkerscript.ld)

# Make executable to depend on that target.
# So, the check whether to relink the executable will be performed
# after possible rebuilding the linker script.
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} my_linkerscript)
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Tsyvarev - that was it! Just a note: with your code, my `set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_linkerscript.ld")` seems no longer necessary; since my template file was empty, the `grep -v '^#' > my_linkerscript.ld` returns 1 because it doesn't let any lines through, so it can be replaced with `COMMAND bash ARGS ... > my_linkerscript.ld ; exit 0"`; and even with that, my linking failes w/ "relocation truncated" - but at least, the CMake side of it now works!

Comment: @sdbbs: Property `LINK_DEPENDS` is still necessary as otherwise **modification** of ldscript won't lead to relinking the executable. (That is, after you edit the ldscript template the ldscript will be regenerated, but the executable remains unchanged.)